# composer repository minimum-stability error

Tags: magento, composer-php

i am trying to install magento extension using composer but i get the following error no matter what i have tried..
 [InvalidArgumentException]

Could not find package mageworx/module-searchsuiteautocomplete at any version for your minimum-stability (st
  able). Check the package spelling or your minimum-stability

my composer looks like that:

```
    "repositories": [
 {
 "type": "artifact",
 "url": "searchextention"
 }
],
```

files are in searchextention folder on root folder.

composer file on extension:

```
{
   "name": "mageworx/module-searchsuiteautocomplete",
   "description": "Search Suite Autocomplete by MageWorx",
   "require": {
       "magento/framework"      : ">=100.0.0 <102",
       "magento/module-catalog" : ">=100.0.0 <103",
       "magento/module-search"  : ">=100.0.0 <101"
   },
   "type": "magento2-module",
   "version": "2.1.3",
   "license": [
       "OSL-3.0",
       "AFL-3.0"
   ],
   "autoload": {
       "files": [
           "registration.php"
       ],
       "psr-4": {
           "MageWorx\\SearchSuiteAutocomplete\\": ""
       }
   }
}
```

how can i solve this??
i am using php 7

Answer (score 0):

Add/change a line in your composer.json file

```
"minimum-stability":"dev"
```